# Second time row not show properly

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

[image]
After ajax success, it shows data in a row If I add first-time new row it adds to see the image 1st but the second time it adds the wrong way

[image]

My code:

```
 <div class="row">
      <div class="col-3">
      </div>
      <div class="col-8">
         <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
               <h4 class="mt-0 header-title">Add Course</h4>
               <form method="POST" id="topic_form" class="form-horizontal well">
                  <fieldset>
                     <div class="repeater-custom-show-hide">
                        <div data-repeater-list="car">
                           <div data-repeater-item="">
                              <div class="form-group row  d-flex align-items-end">
                                 <div class="col-sm-12">
                                    <select  id="mainCatItem" name="mainCatItem" class="form-control">
                                    <option value="">Select Category</option>}
                                    option
                                        <?php foreach($fetchcat as $fetchcategory): ?>
                                          <option value="<?php echo $fetchcategory->main_category_id; ?>"><?php echo $fetchcategory->main_category_name; ?></option>
                                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                                    </select>
                                 </div>
                                 <!--end col-->     
                              <div id="course_show">
                                <div class="row">
                                 <div class="col-sm-6">
                                    <label class="control-label">Course Title</label>
                                    <input type="text" id="coursetitle"  name="coursetitle" class="form-control">
                                 </div>
                                 <!--end col-->
                                 <div class="col-sm-6">
                                    <label class="control-label">Short description</label>
                                    <input type="text" id="shortdesp" name="shortdesp"  class="form-control">
                                 </div>
                                 <div class="col-sm-6">
                                    <label class="control-label">Course Price</label>
                                    <input type="number" id="courseprice" name="courseprice" class="form-control">
                                 </div>
                                 <!--end col-->

                                  <div class="col-sm-12">
                                    <label class="control-label">Page Content</label>
                                    <textarea style="height: 100px !important" type="text" id="page_content" name="page_content" class=" form-control"></textarea>
                                 </div>
                                 <div class="col-sm-12">
                                    <label class="control-label">Long description</label>
                                    <textarea style="height: 100px !important" type="text" id="longdesp" name="longdesp" class=" form-control"></textarea>
                                 </div>
                                 <div class="col-sm-12">
                                    <label class="control-label">Trailer Video link</label>
                                    <input type="text" id="links" name="links" class="form-control">
                                 </div>

                            </div>     
                           </div>     

                              </div>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                   <br><br>

                 <div id="course_show2">
                   <div class="row">
                     <div class="col-12">
                      <h3>Video Detail</h3>
                       <form id="insertvideo" method="post">
                        <table id="addrow" width="100%">
                        <tr>
                          <td><input type="button" class="btn btn-success addButton col-3 offset-1" value="add" /></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="clonetr">
                          <td>Video Title<input type="text" id="videotitle" name="videotitle[]" class="form-control"></td>
                          <td>Video description<input type="text" id="videodesc" name="videodesc[]" class="form-control"></td>
                          <td>Video Links<input type="text" id="videolink" name="videolink[]" class="form-control"></td>
                          <td><input type="button" class="btn btn-danger deleteButton" value="delete" /></td>
                        </tr>
                      </table>
                       </form>  
                     </div>
                   </div>

                    <div class="col-sm-6" style="margin-top: 13px; margin-left: 400px;">
                     <!--  <button type="submit" id="insert"  class="btn btn-primary col-3 offset-1">Get Course</button> -->
                     <button type="submit" id="btn-update"   value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary col-3 offset-1">Save</button>
                  </div>
               </div>

           </fieldset>
         </form>

            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#course_show").hide();
    $("#course_show2").hide();
  });

  $(function(){
    $(".addButton").click(function(){
    $('.clonetr:last').clone(true).appendTo("#addrow");
    $("#addrow tr:last input").val("");
    });
    $(".deleteButton").click(function(){
        if($('.deleteButton').length > 1)

           $(this).closest("tr").remove();
        else
          alert('Atleast one required.');
    });
});

     $('#mainCatItem').change(function(e){
         e.preventDefault();
         var mainCatId = $(this).val();
          $.ajax({
                url: "<?php echo base_url();?>admin_controller/WebsiteContentController/fetchSubDetail1",
                type: "POST",
                data: {mainCatId:mainCatId},
                dataType:'json',
                success: function(response)
                {
                  $("#course_show").show();
                  $("#course_show2").show();
                  console.log(response);
                    console.log(response[0].Category);

                  if(response.length>0){

                  $('#coursetitle').val(response[0].Course_title);
                  $('#shortdesp').val(response[0].Short_description);
                  $('#courseprice').val(response[0].Cource_price);
                  $('#courseduration').val(response[0].Cource_duration);
                  $('#page_content').text(response[0].page_content);
                  $('#longdesp').text(response[0].Long_decription);
                  $('#links').val(response[0].Links);
                  $('#videotitle').val(response[0].video_title);
                  $('#videodesc').val(response[0].video_description);
                  $('#videolink').val(response[0].video_links);

                   $('#btn-update').show();

                  }else{
                  }
                  $.ajax({
                        url: "<?php echo base_url();?>admin_controller/WebsiteContentController/fetchSubDetail",
                        type: "POST",
                        data: {mainCatId:mainCatId},
                        dataType:'html',
                        success: function(response)
                        {
                            $('#addrow tr:not(:first)').remove();
                            $('#addrow').append(response);
                            console.log(response);
                        }
                    });
            }

        });
     });
</script>
```

In my ajax success response have two records.
after two record data shows, I add new rows after `add` button click, But it adds rows in the wrong way I show in the second image.
I want to add a new row after the last record.
This is my full code.

Comment: which type of data in `response` ?

Comment: @DevsiOdedra first two records have in `response`

Comment: if it came from ajax then why field is empty? and why `$('#addrow tr:not(:first)').remove();` ?

Comment: @DevsiOdedra I am adding new rows

Comment: @AnantSingh---AlivetoDie `var mainCatId = $(this).val();`

Comment: I just want to add new empty row when `add` button is clicked after ajax success data shows

Comment: The code you have shown appears to make rather little sense. As people have pointed out, you only appear to be making this AJAX request once, while the page is loading. Since you already remove all rows that aren’t the first from the table in the success callback, you should not even have any rows left to clone afterwards … Please post a _proper_ example that truthfully reflects what you are actually doing, because what you have shown so far, apparently can’t be it.

Comment: I will post full code

Comment: @AnantSingh---AlivetoDie I update my code

Comment: @farhantechno  i am confused, why ajax running inside ajax?? what you are doing or try to do??